# MySQL query to get headlines from subcategories of a given parent

Tags: mysql, join

I have a database structure like this

```
CATEGORIES
ID | parent_id | name
1  | 0         | sports
2  | 1         | football
3  | 1         | tennis
4  | 0         | activities
5  | 4         | hiking
etc.


NEWS
ID | category_id | title              | date       | etc
1  | 2           | Football is great  | 2012-12-21 | 
2  | 3           | Tennis is healthy  | 2012-11-13 |
3  | 5           | Go on hiking       | 2013-11-15 |
```

Now, when I want to get the headlines(titles) of the subcategories of "sports", what is the best way to achieve this?

I was thinking of doing multiple queries (3 in this case).

First, get all childs of "Sports"

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = 1
```

Then, for each result do a query to get the headlines from each subcategory.

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE category_id = (result from query above)
```

In this example, 3 queries will be executed. (One to get all subcategories. There are two subcategories in this case, so two queries will be executed to the news table. That makes a total of 3.)

Or is there a smarter (more efficient) way to do this? Perhaps 1 query?

Comment: You can easily join those two tables. How is the relation between CATEGORIES and NEWS, Is it 1:1 or 1:n? Is it valid to have categories without news?

Comment: Note that by convention, we use NULL and not 0 for orphans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with one query using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT NEWS.*, CATEGORIES.name 
FROM NEWS 
INNER JOIN CATEGORIES ON NEWS.category_id = CATEGORIES.ID
```

You can also write the query using a `LEFT JOIN`. This will allow you to list all categories including those with no news articles.

```
SELECT categories.name as Category_Name, news.*
FROM categories  
LEFT JOIN news ON news.category_id = categories.ID
```

I've put this in a SQL Fiddle to help demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c1b3/6